# Could not load file or assembly AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, upgrade, ajax-control-tookit

I upgrade a site from SP 2010 to SP 2013 and now I am getting following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit,
>   Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I found some solutions at Stackoverflow and they seem to be talking about downloading AjaxControlToolkit from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/109918 and placing it in BIN directory of my web application.
But problem is in current server (SP 2010) the BIN directory is empty so how come it is working there? So that means this is not an issue.

One guy is talking about installing this WSP http://sharepointajax.codeplex.com/releases/view/93640 but again in current SP 2010 server this WSP is not installed and yet it is working fine.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Visual Studio Solution that deploys the Ajax Control Toolkit assembles to the GAC.

[Yes, you can still use the AjaxControlToolkit with SharePoint 2013 on-premises](http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2015/07/yes-you-can-still-use-the-ajaxcontroltoolkit-with-sharepoint-2013-on-premises/)